# how do i update my app sidebar dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, use-state

```
  function TinderCards() {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([
      {
      name: "Model Baby",
      url:"https://www.themodelskit.co.uk/wp- 
        content/uploads/2021/10/shutterstock_1431963185.jpg",
         age:22
  },
  {
   name: "Seema Jaswal",
     url:"https://static.standard.co.uk/2021/06/14/16/euro_2020_live_seema_jaswal_01-1.jpg? 
 width=968&auto=webp&quality=50&crop=968%3A645%2Csmart", 
    age:32
},
{
 name: 'Baby',
 url: '../assets/IMG_20210811_105110_849.webp'
 age: 34
}
]);
```

I am pullin data from a datebase that is like the data i created above for illustration purposes

```
 useEffect(() => {
 const allPeople = query(collection(db, "people"))

   onSnapshot(allPeople, (snapshot) => (
     setPeople(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
   ))

   return () => {
   second
  }
 }, [])
```

I am updating the app with the information from the database

```
  return (
    <div>
    <div className='tinderCards__cardContainer'>
    {people.map((person) => (
        <TinderCard className="swipe" key={person.name} preventSwipe={["up, down"]} onClick= 
 {() => {setPer(person.name)}} >
            <div className='card' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})`}}>
                <h3>{person.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </TinderCard>
    ))}
    </div>
</div>
 )
}

export default TinderCards
```

but how do i update my sidebar with this infomatiom and have the name and other infomation change, eachtime the name changes in the main app

```
   function RightSidebar() {
    return (
      <div className='rightSidebar'>
    <div className='rightSidebar__contents'>
        <h1>About</h1>
        <Card className='rightSidebar__card'>
            <div className='card__nameContents'>
                    <CardHeader className='card__nameAge' title = {name} subheader = {age} 
 avatar = {<VerifiedIcon className='activeIcon verified' />}  />
                    
                <CardHeader className='card__active' title = "active" avatar= 
 {<FiberManualRecordIcon className='activeIcon' />} />
                
            </div>
```

The app is quite small do i really need redux or is there a way to track the changes with useState hook?

Answer (score 0):

How far is the common parent of RightSidebar and TinderCards?
If one level up or not too far, store the people data as state of the common parent, pass the data to right sidebar and a function to update the sidebar to TinderCards.

If common parent is far, you can use the [React Context API (or the useContext hook)](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
You don't need redux for this